# Apache and VB.net: cannot read STDIN

Tags: vb.net, windows, apache, stdin

I am having a really weird issue that I am unable to understand, and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

## Setup

I am running an Apache WebServer on a Windows box, and I have configured it so that .exe files can be executed (e.g. http://mydomain.com/program.exe). The .exe is generated using VB.net.

## Ideal Execution

When I make POST requests to the .exe, the .exe reads the data from STDIN, parses it, and acts accordingly. This approach works fine.

## Error Conditions

Sometimes, many POST requests will come in very close together (about 30 in 1-3 seconds). Under this condition, sometimes one request will have an issue. The issue is that there is no data in STDIN.

## Failed Debugging Approaches So Far

I use the following code in VB.net to get the data:

```
Public Shared Function getPostData() As String
    Dim contentLength = Environ(CGI_CONTENT_LENGTH)
    Dim buffer(contentLength - 1) As Char
    Console.In.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, contentLength)
    getPostData = New String(buffer)
End Function
```

When the error occurs, the return value of `Console.In.ReadBlock` is 0, in other words, there is nothing in STDIN to read.

I have used other functions to do the read, Console.In.ReadToEnd, or even the approach [here](http://www.shamrock-software.eu/cgi.htm).

## Posible Causes

I concluded that one of two things might be happening:

1. Apache is not passing the STDIN data to VB.
2. VB is unable to read STDIN correctly.

I had also assumed the POST data wasn't being sent correctly, but I ruled this out per packet sniffing.

## Weird

Here is where it gets weird: I wrote a perl script that reads from STDIN, and then pipes the data to the .exe, and then takes its output and passes it back. In other words, a perl proxy. When I use this approach, the issue goes away. Which probably means that neither of the two conclusions above is correct.

## Help

Any ideas what could be happening? I'm happy to provide any additional data required.

Comment: In what way to you run the EXE in Apache? As a cgi-script? Or any other way?

Comment: Correct. As a CGI. I added ` AddHandler cgi-script .pl .cgi .exe` in httpd.conf

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239588

Comment: @SamMakin Thanks for that link! I tried it out, but lBytesRead is returning 0 (i.e. it's reading nothing). This happens all the time. I know for sure there should be data to read, since reading from Console.In does return data. Any ideas on what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

You may have problems with data encoding. Have you tried setting the Console's `InputEncoding` property to, let's say, `ASCIIEncoding` (in order to set character size to 1)? Otherwise you should assert the input data is encoded as the default Console's encoding. Notice that if Console's current encoding does not match the input data encoding you will have erratic reads because of reading data in invalid chunks. Of course, you will have to set `OutputEncoding` as well.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try. However, does it make sense to you that if this is the issue, that I would only see it sporadically and not all the time? The bounty has expired, but I'll award it to you regardless if this works.

Comment: Don't worry about the award but about your issue ;-) Indeed, it's strange and I'm not 100% sure, but I faced encoding problems in the past and symptoms are similar: some reads are OK and other fail. Give it a try and let's see...